# PHP does not find strings in a certain html element and throws Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store links of uploaded images to a database via php. It reads all of the elements inside a form. Yet, it does not find the string in here.

```
<div class="hidden" id="FixedIMG1_1" name="FixedIMG1_1">/var/ups/BaianatAqaria60f54840932d7.png </div>
```

`BaianatAqaria60f54840932d7.png` is the value that is generated by a php file and I need to store it to a database.
[image]

I added this line in php `$img1 = (isset($_POST['FixedIMG1_1']));` and `echo "<pre>", $img1, "</pre>";`

and got:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in /var/www/website/homie/pagies/postadData.php on line 85
```

I tried another solution and and wrote this variable like this `$img1 = (isset($_POST['FixedIMG1_1']) ? $_POST['FixedIMG1_1'] : null);`

and the output was no error found, and the variable remained empty. When I tried to store it in my database I got empty values as well.
[image]

As the variable is supposed to be a link, I tried to store it again with `realpath()` in the database, and I only got the directory of my localhost without the string needed.
[image]

Comment: You need to continue like : `$img1 = (isset($_POST['FixedIMG1_1'])) ? $_POST['FixedIMG1_1'] : 'WHATYOUNEEDIFNOEXIST';`

Comment: I can't see any usage of variable named "stmt" in your code, can you please paste more code?

Comment: Do you have code somewhere that extracts the contents of that `<div>` to make it into a form variable? Normally I'd use `<input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="yyy">` to do something like that.

Comment: Yes, I do @droopanoot

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. You haven't shared any PHP code that uses the variable `$stmt`. Also, how is this related to MySQL? Is there anything not working related to the database itself, ilke any `SELECT` or `UPDATE` query?

Comment: @NicoHaase the issue has been resolved. It was from the html tag. If you check the first image you will see that the value does not exist. So, I had to fill the value with the text content in that tag. 

as you requested, here is the php code `$img1 =  $LINK->real_escape_string($_POST['FixedIMG1_1']);`, `$stmt1 = $CONC ->prepare("INSERT INTO *** VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)");

if (isset($img1)) {
    $stmt1->bind_param('ss', $Post_ID, $img1);
    $stmt1->execute();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the issue after too much pain. I simply had to fill the elements's `value="something"`  via `.defaultValue = "something"` 
along with the inner context through `.innerHTML`.
Also, in a certain point I ended up adding `type="file"`  to the HTML tag which prevented the php code to catch the text in the tag. Hence, I removed it and everything went well.

Answer (score 1):

You most send parameter so please change your form to

```
<form action="route" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="FixedIMG1_1" value="/var/ups/BaianatAqaria60f54840932d7.png">
</form>
```

now test the result:

```
$image = $_POST('FixedIMG1_1')
if(isset($image){
   echo "<pre>", $imgage, "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: echo echo ?? :)

Comment: sorry that was a syntax mistake,i fixed that